# How to design a picture in WinUI 3 that automatically adapts to the window

Tags: xaml, user-interface, background-image, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm doing a little software with Winui 3, and now I'm designing the homepage, and I'm hoping to make a scalable image like the Winui 3 Gallery homepage[image: Like this,this background image can automatically adapts to the window's size],but now I can't find any lessons or documents which can teach me how to make a page like this.

I have already designed a navigationview and made a home page(homepage.xaml),it's a winui 3 page file.I'd like to design a background image(/Assets/background.png) which can automatically adapts to the window.If I have anything that is not clearly described, please point it out and I will add it as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: You can get the code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery). You can clone it and see how it's implemented.  The file name of that image is *GalleryHeaderImage.png* and you can see how it's implemented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/3a9999b2a9798ed688484ecf22d837cbc8af1832/WinUIGallery/Controls/HomePageHeaderImage.xaml#L42).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `VisualExtensions.SetNormalizedCenterPoint Method`
to set the CenterPoint is centered even when the visual is resized.

And you could try to refer to the Winui 3 Gallery offical sample which is provided by Andrew:

https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery

https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/3a9999b2a9798ed688484ecf22d837cbc8af1832/WinUIGallery/Controls/HomePageHeaderImage.xaml#L40

Comment: Sorry, I forget this thing(You know,I'm new to stackoverflow).It works!I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI nuget package and based on the WinUI3 Gallery:

```
...
    xmlns:toolkit="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI">

    <Grid>
        <Grid
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="200">

            <Image
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                x:Name="HeroImage"
                Source="/Assets/background.png"
                toolkit:VisualExtensions.NormalizedCenterPoint="0.5"
                Stretch="UniformToFill" >
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```